# How can I create a Pull Request when a release completes in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

A project I'm working on has 2 long-standing feature branches as well as the master branch.

To fully automate deployments, I'd like to create a pull request from master into those two feature branches anytime a deployment goes out from an Azure DevOps Release.

What kind of tooling in Azure DevOps would allow me to do create pull requests as a release task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [Create Pull Request](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) extension, it gives you the ability to create a pull request automatically from your release pipeline with multi target branch:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can create the Pull Request through [Pull Request REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#create-a-pull-request) during the release.

There is [Invoke HTTP REST API task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/http-rest-api) but may not good for your requirement.

The simple way is that you can do it through **PowerShell task**:

1. Select the phase (e.g. Run on agent) and check **Allow scripts to access OAuth token** option. You can use [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/_shared/personal-access-tokens) too.
2. Add PowerShell task

Simple sample:

```
param(
[string]$project,
[string]$repo,
[string]$sourceBranch,
[string]$targetBranch,
[string]$title,
[string]$des,
[string]$token
)
$bodyObj=@{
  "sourceRefName"="refs/heads/$sourceBranch";
  "targetRefName"= "refs/heads/$targetBranch";
  "title"= "$title";
  "description"="$des";
}
$bodyJson=$bodyObj| ConvertTo-Json
$uri="https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo/pullRequests?api-version=3.0"
Write-Output $bodyJson
Write-Output $uri
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "test",$token)))
$result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $bodyJson
```

Arguments: `-project "XXX" -repo "XXX" -sourceBranch "XX" -targetBranch "XX" -title "XX" -des "XX" -token [$(System.AccessToken) or personal access token]`

Comment: It'd be interesting to have those as tasks natively available in VSTS

Comment: @baywet You can build a custom task through VSTS extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer as it appears to be right; although, I didn't test it out myself and switched to trunk-based development where this is no longer an issue. I appreciate you responding so quickly with a thorough solution!

Comment: I'm late to the party, but: i get `"TF401027: You need the Git 'PullRequestContribute' permission to perform this action.` using OAuth Token ($(System.AccessToken)). I have appropriate permission though. Any thougths?

Comment: You could try this alternative authentication method : `$headers = @{ 
       Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
   }
   $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'`