# Create pull requests in Git Bash to Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have ability to create pull requests to GitHub from Git Bash with command `hub pull-request`. Can I create pull request from Git Bash into Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 6):

> Can I create pull request from Git Bash into Azure DevOps?

I think the answer is yes. We could expand the Git aliases with VSTS CLI commands to achieve it.

There is [VSTS CLI interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest) that we could [configure to use git aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/git?view=vsts-cli-latest) including creating pull requests. Also, we could expand the Git aliases with VSTS CLI commands to create pull requests.

For the details, you can check this document:

[Visual Studio and Azure DevOps Git: Extend the git command line with server commands–Part 2](http://hermit.no/visual-studio-and-azure-devops-git-extend-the-git-command-line-with-server-commands-part-2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Relevant power shell REST request example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634358/how-can-i-create-a-pull-request-when-a-release-completes-in-vsts]()

Comment: I normally clone a branch from Azure and then do some work in a newly created develop branch and then make a git commit and git push from inside the "Git bash" shell - it works like a charm - why do I need to setup VSTS CLI to get the git request-pull command to work with Azure ???

Answer (score 2):

I've created one PowerShell script to streamline the process. You can check out the details here

[Git Hub Repo](https://github.com/HainanZhao/Git-Azure-Devops)

Basically what you need to do is:

- Get the Azure DevOps access token
- Pass the token to the PowerShell and let it run the setup steps.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but I wanted to do so directly from Git Bash